# Autoscaling instances in APP engine in Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a table in Google Bigquery that is growing periodically.

I want to use Python and pandas to do some analysis and data transformations and put it again in Google Bigquery.

I want to make it auto-scalable, and I mean by that, increase the power of a single machine(vertical scaling), because the more the data increase the more power I need into the machine. It can be done with the service in Google Cloud called App engine flexible environment? Is this service going to scale up automatically depending on the amount of data that has to process?

Or there isn't a service in google cloud that can scale up automacitally and I will have to create an instance and scale up manually depending on the amount of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine scales horizontally, it creates more instances to be able to attend multiple requests so it would not be a fitting solution for what you are seeking.

Also, there is no service that scales the instance type in GCP automatically, you would indeed need to create a bigger instance yourself.

What you can do is to create an alert with something like Stackdriver and then go to create the instance.

Hope you will find this useful!